# jQuery check if Attr Class exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, html

How do I determine if the `.attr('class')` exists?

I am using this code:

```
if(jQuery(this).attr('class') != undefined && jQuery(this).hasClass('myclass')) {
  //Do something
}
```

It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Just wondering why you are checking if the attr class exists. the `hasClass` will check if it has a class and is usually enough

Comment: will it check if it's `undefined` however ?

Comment: @Tom: The function is doing what it says. If the `class` attribute does not exist or it is empty, then obviously the element does not have the class. Why don't you just try it: http://jsfiddle.net/sP9YR/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It depends on what you want. Do you want to check if an element has the class attribute, such as:

```
<div class></div>
<div class=""></div>
<div class="abc"></div>
```

If so, use:

```
if ($('div').attr('class') != undefined)...
```

If you're trying to check if the element has a specific class, use:

```
if ($('div').hasClass('abc'))...
```

Comment: what if I want to check both ? or `hasClass` does this implicitly anyway ?

Comment: Yes, if an element doesn't have the class attribute, and you do, say, $(...).hasClass('abc'), it'll just return false automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

> ```
> if(jQuery('#id1').attr('class') =="") {
>        alert($('#id1').attr('class'));
>   }
> ```
>
> `<div id="id1">test</div>`

Answer (score 2):

You can check if an element with any class exists by just calling 'length' on a jquery object.

```
$('.myclass').length
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value if the attribute class doesn't exists is null or an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

this code works actually: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReHjN/)

HTML:

```
<div></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="blah"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="myclass andAnotherClass"></div>​
```

JS:

```
$("div").each(function(){
if(jQuery(this).attr('class') != undefined && jQuery(this).hasClass('myclass')) {
  jQuery(this).html("I have it");
      } else {
          jQuery(this).html("I don't have it");
      }
});​
```